Fix hostname resolution in Fritz!Box local network
Situation:

I have a home network with a Fritz!Box 6690 Cable as the network mesh master. The Fritzbox has setup DynDNS so that the hostname drandarov.io points to my Public IP.
I also have a HTTPS Server (just temporary for testing, no cert etc.) on Port 443 on a machine that I want to forward to. This means https://drandarov.io should be redirected to that server. For that I set up a Port Forwarding rule that redirects that port to my machine.

My issue now is:

From an external network https://drandarov.io works as intended. https://<public-ip> also works as intended.

However: From the local network https://<public-ip> works as intended, but https://drandarov.io point to https://fritz.box or respectively https://<fritzbox ip> instead of the intended machine

In conclusion: hostname resolves to my public IP in external network, but to my fritzbox IP in the local network.


How can I resolve the issue with local hostname resolution?
Solutions:
Option 1

See answer by Zac67

Option 2
AVM has this document (Knowledge document "#3525") in the depths of their documentation, that Google put on page 3 for my search *sigh*: https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-7490/3525_Cannot-access-an-HTTPS-server-in-the-home-network/
Essentially the Fritz!Box only supports one Update URL and in my case with IONOS (and I assume many other), they have separate Update URLs for IPv4 and IPv6.This results in the following:

"The device therefore receives the FRITZ!Box's IPv6 WAN address in response to its DNS query for the IPv6 address for the MyFRITZ! address or the dynamic DNS domain name. Since there is no network address translation (NAT) in IPv6, the device then accesses the FRITZ!Box itself via HTTPS."

In conclusion this sounds like a big design fail from AVM with their DynDNS setting.
My final solution is to host a different DynDNS updater on my server that supports updating both IP types.

Like most consumer-grade routers with integrate DNS, a Fritzbox doesn't support split-brain DNS.
So, if you cannot provide another DNS server for PCs in your private LAN, then you need to solve the problem locally, ie. by editing the /etc/hosts (Linux) or C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file.
Within the hosts file, you add a new line e.g.
192.168.1.10 drandarov.io

to make the PC contact that private IP address instead of resolving the name externally.
With an alternative DNS server, you'd add an A record for drandarov.io to 192.168.1.10 (the server's private IP). Also you need to instruct the Fritzbox to assign that alternative DNS server to DHCP clients, instead of the integrated one.

How could I achieve that with the hosts fiel? Especially considering that I don't have a static IP. Apart form that: Would something like pi-hole be an appropriate solution for that?

I've added some detail to the answer, thought the hint was sufficient.

Thanks for the edit. I assume if I have some ports pointing to one machine and some ports pointing to another, the hosts file option would no longer cover that, right? That's why I didn't quite understand the hosts suggestion at first.

You were only talking about HTTPS, ie. port 443. With multiple private servers you'd need to use different host names. For public DNS, you could CNAME all the extra ones to drandarov.io.

Is the fact that other ports like drandarov.io:34200 get resolved locally without a problem relevant?

Ports don't get resolved, host names do. Name resolution from the application might differ though. The alternative DNS or hosts file approach work all the same.

Sorry for mixing that up. What I'm trying to understand is: Wouldn't that behavior mean that drandarov.io:443 and drandarov.io:32400 would resolve do different IPs? So only the port 443 has that issue at all Another interesting point is that when calling curl https://drandarov.io from WSL from the same machine with that error it correctly resolves to the HTTPS Server and not the Fritz Box

Unless both applications use different name resolution methods (perhaps mDNS), the resolved IP is the same. Just use different names for different services, mapping to different private IP addresses in your LAN, and the same public IP on the Internet.

Wouldn't that mean that fritz.box:32400 would resolve to the same machine as drandarov.io:32400, the same as fritz.box:443 and drandarov.io:443? However, fritz.box:32400 doesn't work. Sorry for the stupid questions I'm a noob when it comes to DNS.

fritz.box is the private IP of  your router. The port forwarding is from the public IP.

After a lot of searching (Google page 3) i found this documentation: https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-7490/3525_Cannot-access-an-HTTPS-server-in-the-home-network/
Does this mean I could host a DDNS Updater on my machine instead of using the Fritz.Box setting to resolve the issue?

I added my final solution to my original post, but will still mark your answer as correct :)
